# Interpretation of binomial regression in R

Tags: r, regression, logistic, correlation

I'm running a regression to see if there is a positive or negative relationship between `cvdrslt` and `smkcigst`, but I'm not sure how to interpret this regression. Also why is the data for `smkcigst` NA, even though the dataset has no NAs for it and instead has 1 for all observations?

Does this regression show that there is a positive or a negative relationship between the two variables? I'm also having trouble creating plots because the plot only shows 2 points, please help me write a code to plot this regression.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Notice the message above your output table: "Coefficients: 1 not defined because of singularities". You do not have an estimate for that variable. This happened because you can express one of your columns as a linear combination of some others. You can also see very high standard errors in your table which even if you didn't have perfect multicollinearity would show something is wrong. To answer your question though, if you did have a coefficient for smkcigst_a, a positive coefficient would mean there is a positive association between the response and smkcigst_a.

Comment: Actually the NA happens because "smkcigst has 1 for all observations". This means that smkcigst is indistinguishable from the intercept. How do you expect to observe a correlation between a variable that is always 1 and another variable? Note: As @fmtcs points out, in general NA's in the summary table indicate exact linear dependency between predictors. But in your case, we can identify the cause even more precisely.

Comment: @dipetkov Whoops, I missed that in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

> [...] why is the data for smkcigst NA, even though the dataset has no NAs for it and instead has 1 for all observations?

The answer lies in your question: `smkcigst` just consists of ones, so there is *no variation* in this variable. If e.g. this variable measures the amount of smoked cigarettes, your sample only consists of smokers and you have no non-smokers to compare them to.

A more technical answer was already given in `@fmtcs` comment: a linear regression estimated via OLS does not allow that a variable is a "linear combination of some others", and since the `intercept` already consists of only ones, `smkcigst` is such a linear combination. This is why `glm`function automatically drops it.

> Does this regression show that there is a positive or a negative relationship between the two variables?

No, because there is no variation in `smkcigst`

> I'm also having trouble creating plots because the plot only shows 2 points, please help me write a code to plot this regression.

If both variables are binary, the plot is correct. Consider this: `smkcigst` only has value $1$, while `cvdrslt` can take values $1$ and $0$. Then, there are only two possible combinations: $(1, 0)$ and $(1, 1)$. Since observations overlay each other, you could use some *jitter* to improve plotting, e.g. by using `geom_jitter()` from the package `ggplot2`.